# Find and remove non-compliant characters from string

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form in that I need to validate longtitude and latitude fields.

Code below works well with capturing the `keypress`. However in the `focusout` part there are two problems that I just can't figure out:

1/ it is supposed to replace the "not allowed" characters in the field with '', that does not happen

2/ the alert is never triggered

Code looks like this:

```
    var allowedLongLat = "0123456789.-";

    $("#latitude").keypress( function(e) {
        var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (allowedLongLat.indexOf(chr) < 0)
        {
            alert("The character "+chr+" is not allowed in this field!");
            return false;
        }
    });
    $(document).on("focusout","#latitude",function(){
        var str = $("#latitude").val();
        var wrongchars = [];
        var wrongalert = "";
        for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (allowedLongLat.indexOf(str[i]) < 0)
            {
                wrongchars.push(str[i]);
            }
        }
        jQuery.each(wrongchars , function(index, value){
             $("#latitude").val( str.replace(\'/\'+value+\'/g\', \'\') );
             wrongalert += value;
        });                 
        if ( wrongalert.lenght > 1 )
        {
            alert("The characters "+wrongalert+" are not allowed in this field!");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas what I am missing out?

Comment: Just to be sure, we're talking decimal degrees, right? For example: -4.32135123, 15.5123123, yes?

Comment: yes, for google maps coords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some errors in code

```
$("#latitude").val( str.replace(\'/\'+value+\'/g\', \'\') );
```

has some typo mistake,

```
if ( wrongalert.lenght > 1 )
```

typo error, it should be length.

I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e64fy7vr/4/) jsfiddle.

```
var allowedLongLat = "0123456789.-";

$(document).on("focusout","#latitude",function(){
    var str = $("#latitude").val();
    var wrongchars = [];
    var wrongalert = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (allowedLongLat.indexOf(str[i]) < 0)
        {
            wrongchars.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(wrongchars);
    jQuery.each(wrongchars , function(index, value){
        console.log(value);
         $("#latitude").val( $("#latitude").val().replace(value, '') ); // I simplified here
         wrongalert += value;
    });     
    if ( wrongalert.length > 1 )// here was typo error
    {
        alert("The characters "+wrongalert+" are not allowed in this field!");
    }
});
```